# "Chiunque altro" oppure "qualunque altro"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, pronouns

In [questo articolo](http://www.ilfoglio.it/economia/2016/12/28/news/voucher-cosa-sono-e-perche-e-un-problema-ampiamente-sopravvalutato-112775/) si può leggere

> La ricerca dell’INPS lo spiega meglio di **chiunque altro**: “Anche i voucher possono essere aboliti. Ma ciò che non può essere abolito è il problema sottostante: come si pagano le attività di breve durata”.

In questo testo, il costrutto "chiunque altro" mi è sembrato un po' strano: potrebbe essere sostituito dall'espressione ["qualunque altro"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/qualunque/)?

Comment: In effetti, "la ricerca" non è una persona, quindi sembra strano l'utilizzo di "chi"; in questo caso il "chi" è usato in modo impersonale quindi potrebbe essere corretto, ma non riesco a pronunciarmi sul fatto se sia effettivamente giusto oppure una forzatura entrata nel linguaggio comune.
L'equivalente sarebbe:
"la ricerca dell'INPS lo spiega meglio di _qualunque altra (ricerca)_"

Comment: @Riccardo: Ma  il confronto non è con altre ricerche: è con chiunque abbia detto qualcosa sui voucher, a quel che pare.

Comment: @DaG la tua spiegazione mi sembra la più corretta; la frase equivalente da me citata è corretta nel caso in cui si voglia restringere la comparazione alle sole ricerce.

Comment: @Riccardo: D'accordo: se nel discorso si stessero paragonando varie ricerche, e si volesse privilegiare quella dell'Inps, "chiunque altro" non sarebbe corretto.

Comment: “La ricerca dell’INPS lo spiega molto bene” sarebbe meno ambiguo e sgrammaticato.

Comment: @egreg: “La ricerca dell’INPS lo spiega molto bene” dice qualcosa di diverso, non contiene quel senso di superlativo relativo. E non direi che l'uso di “chiunque” sia addirittura “sgrammaticato”, semmai un po' libero. Dopotutto si parla di un testo scritto da un essere umano, non di un oggetto o di un fenomeno naturale. E comunque, parlare di un testo come di una persona mi sembra una naturale estensione del normalissimo uso secondo cui un testo “dice”, “parla”, “spiega” (come qui) etc.

Comment: "Qualunque altra [ricerca]" sarebbe stata l'espressione ideale da utilizzare, o ancora "L'INPS lo spiega meglio di chiunque altro nella sua ricerca". Non è raro trovare questo tipo di errori negli articoli di giornale, purtroppo.

Comment: @IginoBoffa: "Qualunque altra [ricerca]", come già dicevamo sopra e qui sotto, significa un'altra cosa. Il confronto non è solo (anzi, per niente) con altre ricerche.

Comment: (Ma guarda se mi tocca difendere *Il foglio*! :-) )

Comment: Credo si possa interpretare come un caso di **prosopopea** (*ricerca come oggetto personificato*), o, se si vuole, di **metonimia** (*la ricerca per gli autori della ricerca*).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Intanto, "qualunque altro" da solo non si potrebbe dire, perché "qualunque" è un aggettivo e non un pronome, a differenza di "chiunque".

In questo caso, poi, si sta confrontando quella ricerca con tutte le altre persone e cose che si sono espresse sui voucher. Direi quindi che in questo caso "chiunque altro" sia l'unico modo per esprimersi, anche perché si parla di un testo scritto da esseri umani, non di un oggetto o di un fenomeno naturale.

Comment: Dissento: “chiunque” è un pronome personale e non può riferirsi a “ricerca” o a cose in generale.

Comment: Nell'articolo si menzionano varie persone e cose: uomini politici, ricercatori, docenti, governi, leggi e si conclude che le parole migliori sono state espresse da quella ricerca. Peraltro, la stessa ricerca era stata citata almeno tre volte in precedenza, menzionandone gli autori per nome e poi richiamandoli con “i ricercatori”. Quindi sono anche chiare le persone fisiche a cui si sta facendo riferimento.

Comment: +1 A me pare evidente che *chiunque* è associato ad *INPS*, non a *ricerca* (e sì, vi è un leggero abuso nel parlare di un ente come di una persona, ma mi pare più che accettabile).

Comment: @Charo: Non so che cosa avesse in mente chi ha scritto l'esempio con “qualunque altro”, ma come vedi dal resto della voce, a parte usi desueti, “qualunque” è solo un aggettivo. Nell'uso moderno, sentendo “qualunque altro” viene da chiedere “qualunque altro *cosa*”?

Comment: +1 @egreg Credo che "_chiunque_" sia un pronome personale tanto quanto "_chi_", e non credo si possa considerare sbagliata la frase "A _chi_ bisogna chiedere, all'INPS o all'ufficio XYZ ?".